# Align button at bottom of floating div

Tags: html, css

I have an overview page with tiles and I use the matchheight library to dynamically determine the height of a row. Now I would like to align the 'more' buttons at the bottom of the div so that it doesn't look as messy as in the screenshot on smaller screens.

I tried making the button "position: absolute" with "bottom: 20px" and "left: 40%" but that causes problems with responsiveness. On some resolutions that's okay, but on other's the button is too far to the right.

Can I solve this in a nice way without having to use the media attribute for each resolution?

```css
/* Block: Overview */
#overview {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.overview {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.overview img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.card-title {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.card-subtitle {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: -1rem;
    line-height: 1.7857;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn-card {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-color: #404040;
    color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    horiz-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.btn-card:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #404040;
    border-color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 overview row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center wow fadeInLeft">
                <img alt="Heavy Entertainment Show" src="/images/discography/the-heavy-entertainment-show-1.jpg">
            </div>
            <h3 class="card-title">Heavy Entertainment Show</h3>
            <h4 class="card-subtitle">November 4<sup>th</sup>, 2016</h4>
            <a href="/album/the-heavy-entertainment-show/" title="Show details of Heavy Entertainment Show">
                <button class="btn btn-card">MORE</button>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 overview row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center wow fadeInLeft">
                <img alt="Under the Radar Vol 1" src="/images/discography/under-the-radar-vol-1-1.jpg">
            </div>
            <h3 class="card-title">Under the Radar Vol 1</h3>
            <h4 class="card-subtitle">December 1<sup>st</sup>, 2014</h4>
            <a href="/album/under-the-radar-vol-1/" title="Show details of Under the Radar Vol 1">
                <button class="btn btn-card">MORE</button>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 overview row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center wow fadeInLeft">
                <img alt="Swings Both Ways" src="/images/discography/swings-both-ways-1.jpg">
            </div>
            <h3 class="card-title">Swings Both Ways</h3>
            <h4 class="card-subtitle">November 18<sup>th</sup>, 2013</h4>
            <a href="/album/swings-both-ways/" title="Show details of Swings Both Ways">
                <button class="btn btn-card">MORE</button>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 overview row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center wow fadeInLeft">
                <img alt="Take the Crown" src="/images/discography/take-the-crown-1.jpg">
            </div>
            <h3 class="card-title">Take the Crown</h3>
            <h4 class="card-subtitle">November 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2012</h4>
            <a href="/album/take-the-crown/" title="Show details of Take the Crown">
                <button class="btn btn-card">MORE</button>
            </a>
        </div>
```

[image: Overview]

Comment: Please post the html code that goes with your css.

Comment: A code snippet is useless when you have no markup: please ensure that you are sharing a minimal, concrete and *verifiable* example.

Comment: I'm using external libraries, which are too big to include, so I thought I add the URL to the page. This is the HTML I use (which also gets an error if I try to add it): view-source:http://test.rwdb.info/albums/

Comment: [Edit] code into the question; do not post it as a comment. I also had to remove that link, because several users were flagging it as inappropriate. Apparently it has a semi-nude picture on one of the album covers.

Comment: If the entirety of the code is too long, you should try creating a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. The current snippet doesn't: the buttons are aligned neatly in the center.

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm new on stackoverflow (not the account, but in posting). I updated the post with the relevant HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution, adding a "transform:translateX(-50%);" for alignment. Thanks for the help!

```css
.btn-card {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-color: #404040;
    color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
```

Comment: I am not sure if you have tried Flexbox yet, but it's easier to do all of this with Flex.

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try it, thanks for the insight.